# wordpress, inserting values into custom post type not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When processing the form i want the values to be inserted into the custom post type `products`.

Here is what i have done so far

```
 $art_title = $_POST['art_title'];

    $i = 0;
    foreach($art_title as $value) {
    $art_title = $_POST['art_title'][$i];
    $art_width = $_POST['art_width'][$i];
    $art_height = $_POST['art_height'][$i];
    $art_price = $_POST['art_price'][$i];
    $art_creation_date = $_POST['art_creation_date'][$i];
 $art_upload = $_FILE['art_upload'][$i];

       // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
        $new_post = array(
            'post_title'    => $art_title,
            'post_status'   => 'draft',    
            'post_type' => 'products'
        );
        //save the new post
        $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post); 
        $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'art_upload', $pid );

        if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
            // There was an error uploading the image.
        } else {
            // The image was uploaded successfully!
        }

    $i++;
    }
```

I used media_handle_upload along with the post id but this isn't working.

What i want to know is how do i insert these $_POST values into the custom post type `products` along with the image as `product_image`?

The custom post type is the woocommerce `products`.

Any help greatly appreciated. An example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

please replace this line

$art_upload = $_FILE['art_upload'][$i];

to

$art_upload = $_FILES['art_upload'][$i];